# How to convert IP Address to IP HostEntry in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, ip, ip-address

I'm building a small application that will change your IP address after you type it into a masked text box. I'm really close to figuring it out, but I need help with the h = myNewIP part, as I can't convert from an IP address to an IP Host Entry :

```
Public Class MainForm
Dim h As System.Net.IPHostEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName)
Dim myNewIP As System.Net.IPAddress
Dim myIPEndPoint As System.Net.IPEndPoint
Dim strLocalIp As String

Private Sub
        myNewIP = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(TextBox1.Text)
        myIPEndPoint = New System.Net.IPEndPoint(myNewIP, 0)
        h = myNewIP
        ipTextBox.Text = myNewIP.ToString
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IPEndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("your ip"), 1111);
```

Just a piece of advice in relation to this lines:

```
Dim h As System.Net.IPHostEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName)
Dim myNewIP As System.Net.IPAddress
Dim myIPEndPoint As System.Net.IPEndPoint
Dim strLocalIp As String
```

If they are used in one method only declare them locally.