# Error on Endpoint creation

Tags: vb.net, runtime-error, udpclient

I get the error
*La conversión de la cadena 127.0.0.1 en el tipo 'Long' no es válida.*

on the line

```
Dim EndPoint As New System.Net.IPEndPoint(Host, CInt(Port))
```

I'm trying to create an UDPClient to send data to an application on the same server that is listening on a specific UDP port.

I tried the application in mi PC and works ok and the IP seems to be correct.

What can be wrong?

Comment: You have not provided sufficient code to analyze the problem. However, the error message (in Spanish) is translated into English (Google Translate) as `The conversion of the string 127.0.0.1 to the 'Long' type is invalid.`

Comment: I solved by adding some code to convert the IP in the string to an IPAddress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added some code to convert the IP in the string based on the question [How to convert IP Address to IP HostEntry in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697299/how-to-convert-ip-address-to-ip-hostentry-in-vb-net)

```
Dim myNewIP As System.Net.IPAddress
myNewIP = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(Host)
Dim EndPoint As New System.Net.IPEndPoint(myNewIP, CInt(Port))
```

Comment: @JeffZeitlin The system don't allow me.